# How to use VBA to get permutations of "yes" and "No" across 5 columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

I need to list all the permutations of Yes/No across five columns.  For example, {Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes}, {Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No}, {Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No}, {Yes,Yes,No,No,No}, etc...
[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hgXh.png)

Problem is I only came up with those few and I think the total is 120...  Is there some VBA code I can run to get ALL the permutations?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need VBA to do this. The following worksheet formula gets you there.

Select cell `B2` and paste this formula:

```
=CHOOSE(1+MID(LEFT("00000",5-LEN(DEC2BIN(32-ROW()+1)))&DEC2BIN(32-ROW()+1),COLUMN()-1,1),"No","Yes")
```

Now copy that formula to this range: `B2:F33`

That's it.

Of course, afterward, you may want to copy the results and Paste As Values to have hard values in the cells instead of formulas.

---

And here is how to do it in VBA, should you prefer a coded solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DisplayYesNoPerms()
    Dim rows&, cols&
    cols = 5
    rows = 2 ^ cols
    [b2].Resize(rows, cols) = YesNoPerms(rows, cols)
End Sub

Function YesNoPerms(rows&, cols&)
    Dim i&, j&, t$, v
    ReDim v(0 To rows - 1, 1 To cols)
    For i = 0 To rows - 1
        t = Format(DecToBin(i), String(cols, "0"))
        For j = 1 To cols
            v(i, j) = IIf(Mid(t, j, 1), "No", "Yes")
        Next
    Next
    YesNoPerms = v
End Function

Function DecToBin$(ByVal n&)
    Do
        DecToBin = n Mod 2 & DecToBin
        n = n \ 2
    Loop While n
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Yours was the fastest and easiest to implement solution. I thought I needed VBA, but you proved me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you a VBA solution, but an algorithm that you can implement: just think of every "No" as a number 0, and a "Yes" as a number 1. You create all numbers in the binary system, from "00000" to "11111" (so from 0 to 31).

So, what you need to do:

```
You take every number from 0 to 31, and for every number:
  You convert it into binary format.
  In that binary format, replace every 0 by a "No" and every 1 by a "Yes".
  Find a way to fill your Excel sheet with the corresponding results.
```

Good luck

Comment: It's 2^n... Five columns, so... 0 to 31.

Answer (score 2):

This should print all combinations to the respective rows/columns. User is required to select the top left cell just below the header.

```
Dim i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long, iiii As Long, iiiii As Long
Dim j As Long, jj As Long
Dim str As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr(1) As String
arr(0) = "yes"
arr(1) = "no"
Dim arr_rows() As String
Dim arr_columns() As String

' five nested loops (each for a column)
' the idea is to have all possibilities (yes or no) covered
' each row is taken care of by adding vbNewLine
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
 For ii = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
  For iii = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
   For iiii = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    For iiiii = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
     str = str & arr(i) & "," & arr(ii) & "," & arr(iii) & "," & arr(iiii) & "," & arr(iiiii) & vbNewLine
    Next iiiii
   Next iiii
  Next iii
 Next ii
Next i

' splitting the string created in the loop by new line character
' (i.e. obtaining an array with an element for each row)
' for each row splitting by a comma
' (i.e. obtaining another array with an element for each column)
arr_rows = Split(str, vbNewLine)
Set rng = Selection
For j = LBound(arr_rows) To UBound(arr_rows)
    arr_columns = Split(arr_rows(j), ",")
    For jj = LBound(arr_columns) To UBound(arr_columns)
        rng.Offset(j, jj) = arr_columns(jj)
    Next jj
Next j
```

Comment: Perhaps you should dimension all of the variables.

Comment: And yeah, your code does not work. Did you test it?

Comment: @Warcupine sorry about that. I updated the code now.

Comment: @ExcelHero no, I am afraid I didn't. I don't have Excel at my disposal right now.

Comment: Think OP wanted to spread results over five columns. ... and as smiling side note: reading [Coding Horror article about"arrow code"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

Comment: @T.M. this should be fairly easy, but I have added this part for the sake of completeness. I don't agree five nested loops are "coding horror" in this example. Could you please suggest how to tackle this problem in a better fashion? You could possible try to do cartesian product, but I am not aware how to do this in VBA.

Comment: I have also tried to dimension all the variables as @ExcelHero suggested.

Comment: No, your code isn't horrible +:), it was intended as possibly interesting "smiling" reading regarding *avoidable* "arrow" coding ... *omlouvám se* :-; @Jakub.Novotny

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny I edited my answer. It now includes a VBA solution as well.